# Selenium WebDriver click() does not work on a specific button

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am very new to python, and have started by writing a few web scrapers to help me automate the things I used to do manually - typically new project postings.

I have been writing a web scraper using Selenium that logs into a website and checks for new postings. I use the Advanced Search function on the site to add a number of product categories to a search. This all works until the final 'Ok' button on the Advanced Search page. From what I can tell, the page appears to update, but doesn't move forward. It then throws out a timeout exception error for Line 62, which is the first wait-click command at the beginning of the loop. This tells me it thinks it has clicked the final Ok button, but for some reason it hasn't.

The odd thing is, while the script is running, I can physically click the 'Ok' button and it moves on to the next iteration of the loop and adds the next category. I have tried this manually and can cycle through all of the 13 categories I have defined, but from some reason the click() command does not work on this button.

Here is the code for this section:

```
# A loop that cycles through each of the product categories and adds them to the list
for category in categories:
    # click on add Product and Service Categories
    wait.until(expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="_qfjkvd"]/div/div'))).click()
    # enter search category into the Keyword Text Box
    wait.until(expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="_esjgid"]'))).send_keys(category)
    # click the search button
    wait.until(expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="_uch5x"]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]'))).click()
    # Select the result
    wait.until(expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="_8xkond"]/td[1]/input'))).click()
    # Click the Add button
    wait.until(expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="_fsu5z"]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]'))).click()
    # Add this item to search criteria
    wait.until(expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="_khfknd"]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]'))).click()
```

I have used an explicit wait function, with a 60 second timeout - some of the pages on this site load very slowly.

Here is the .html for the button that I am struggling with.

```
<td tabindex="0" bh="TB" id="_khfknd" class="discHiliteBtn" _cl="discHiliteBtn" title="Save changes">
  <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="btnL">
          <div></div>
        </td>
        <td class="btnC">OK </td>
        <td class="btnR">
          <div></div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</td>
```

Sometimes the class = "btnC", which is the block at the center of the button shows as it does above, but sometimes it shows as follows:

```
<td class="btnC" awmousedown="true" awmouseup="true">OK
```

I have tried a few different methods of identifying the button - I have tried Xpath, Classname, ID and CSS Selector for the overall button - id "_khfknd" - and XPath and Classname for the center of the button itself - class "btnC". None of these seem to work.

I have also gone through some of the suggestions and tried double clicking and using send_keys Enter and Return.

Comment: Is the OK button in an IFRAME or shadow-root?

Comment: There IFRAME text on the header of the page, but nothing on the specific button. The IFRAME text seems to deal with automatic timeouts. I don't know how to find if there is a shadow root, but there is a script type = "text/javascript" section in the header that opens with VAR DOM = Ariba.DOM. Could that be an instruction to set up a shadow root?

Comment: The shadow-root would be fairly obvious... it's on it's own line and is a different color text, at least in the Chrome devtools. In your included code, I don't see the line where you click the OK button. Am I missing it? Is it mislabeled? This is going to be very difficult to debug without seeing the page.

Comment: I am using Chrome and I don't see any lines with different colors, so assume no shadow root.

Comment: The last line in the code is the one that clicks the OK button. ```wait.until(expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="_khfknd"]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]'))).click()```

Comment: I tried with the following code and got it did click the OK button and move the loop forward one iteration, but not after that.                              `okbutton = driver.find_element(By.ID, '_khfknd')
        ActionChains(driver)\
            .click(okbutton)\
            .perform()`

Comment: Add a link to the page and maybe we can help you. Otherwise, I don't know what else we can do.

Answer (score 0):

Try to click on the OK button using JavaScript. See if that works:

```
ok_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//td[@class='btnC']")))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", ok_button)
```

Comment: Hi Shawn, I tried this but get the same error as before.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply access the class and also

```
abc = driver.getelement(By.Classname, "YOur class name here") 
abc.click()
```

and if you want to access using Xpath same thing you can implement it there

Comment: Hi Faizan, I tried this but got the same result as with the original code.

Comment: search_btn = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, value="//*[@id=\"app\"]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/form/button")
                    search_btn.click()

Comment: try this but add your own value through right click on button and copy the right x path like that